# Checking variable if it is set breaks the program in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm just learning CGI and I got stuck on this little program without being able to understand why it is not working. If I don't check if the username is set, then the program runs but if I do it doesn't. I am trying to check whether username is set before I print it. I checked on-line and found a link that explains how to check if something is set in CGI [how to check if variable is set](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=598879) and I am doing it the same way here. I also tried `if($username)` which didn't work. My code is below, I keep staring at it and it seems like I am doing everything right. Can someone point out my mistake?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI qw(:standard);

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $username = $cgi->param("username");
my $password = $cgi->param("password");

if (defined $username) 
   print "username: $username";

print header,
      start_html,
      start_form,
      "Username: ",
      textfield(name=>"username"),p,
      password_field(name=>"password"),
      submit,
      hr, end_html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a pair of curly braces. This:

```
if (defined $username) 
   print "username: $username";
```

should be:

```
if (defined $username) {
   print "username: $username";
}
```

Since you only have a single statement in the `if` block, you can also write it like this:

```
print "username: $username" if defined $username;
```

You can use the module [`CGI::Carp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Carp) to make debugging your CGI programs easier by turning on `fatalsToBrowser`:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

This will cause fatal errors to be displayed in your browser so you don't have to hunt through your web server's error logs. Only use this feature in development code, or you could reveal the internal workings of your program to potential attackers.

---

As RobEarl pointed out in the comments, you're also trying to print the username before printing your HTTP headers. This will confuse the browser, since instead of the default

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

you will be sending something like

```
username: fooContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

As a side note, please make sure you sanitize *all* user input before doing anything with it.

Comment: so in Perl the brackets are always required, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: You also have taint checking enabled, `-T`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks your answer fixed my problem; however, I make the changes you suggested but the username is still not being printed, could it be that the way my code is structured it is writing over the username by printing the form?

Comment: @Stochastic13 Are you sure you're setting the `username` param in your request?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot yes I'm typing it in to the textfield. I also checked with Developer Tools and it is being sent as POST but for some reason not printing to the browser screen.

Comment: @Stochastic13 You're printing it above the `header`.